# Decodificar cadena enviada de GPS GT02A a un servidor

Tags: linux, servidor, gps

qué tal.

Algunos compañeros estamos haciendo una aplicación móvil que trabajará con un GPS para ubicar un vehículo, el GPS es un GT02A y lo hemos configurado para que se conecte a un servidor y en este mande la información que necesitamos (latitud, longitud, imei, etc).

El problema que tenemos es que la información que recibimos en el servidor es una cadena que está codificada pero no sabemos cómo decodificarla o si hemos omitido algo para que la información llegue correctamente.

La información que llega es de este estilo y es mandada por GPRS:

```
message part recieved:(027044957439BR00180319A2548.8997N10859.8106W000.1235919000.0001000000L00000000)
```

[image: Información recibida del GPS]

¿Cómo podríamos manejar la información?

Saludos.

Comment: Mira el siguiente enlace https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/issues/661 tal vez te sea de alguna utilidad

Comment: Por lo que entendí, en el tema, a él le llega la información en Hexadecimal y creo que es más fácil de tratar, el problema es que no sé cómo está codificada, pero entendí un poco mejor cómo funciona, gracias por la información.